# How to add image in jframe in java swing?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

How to add image . i want to add image only above line not on whole jframe how can i do this in jframe swing. i tried but i ma able to set background image on whole screen.i need to set an background only above line.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;
public class Demo1 extends JFrame
{

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);  // fixes the immediate problem.
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Line2D lin = new Line2D.Float(20, 150, 1350, 150);
        g2.draw(lin);
    }       

  public Demo1(  )
  {
      {
      getContentPane().setBackground(new java.awt.Color(240,255,255));
      }     
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      Container c = getContentPane();
      c.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
      setUndecorated(true);
      Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
      setBounds(0,0,screenSize.width, screenSize.height); 
 }

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
      Demo1 frame = new Demo1();
      frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And for adding a image you can use `g.drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, ImageObserver observer)` in `paint()` function.

or

Make a `JLabel` and add [image icon](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/jlabel/create-jlabel-with-imageicon-and-text/) to it

Comment: Does `JFrame` even _have_ a `paintComponent` method?

Comment: You had the right idea. But maybe also suggest to use a `JPanel` to paint, _with_ the `paintComponent` method. `JFrame` and other top-level components should not be painted on, as they already carry the load of painting components and aren't double buffered.

Answer (score 1):

//Global Declaration

```
private BufferedImage bi;
```

//SomeWhere

```
try {
        bi = ImageIO.read(new File("C:/1.jpg"));//Write path of your image here
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClassName.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);//Change ClassName to your class Name
    }


    final JPanel panel = new JPanel(){
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            Graphics g2 = g.create();
            g2.drawImage(bi, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
            g2.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
            return new Dimension(bi.getWidth()/2, bi.getHeight()/2);
        }
    };

    mainPanel.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //Add other components to mainPanel
    frm.add(mainPanel);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyImagePanel extends JPanel{ 
    BufferedImage image;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(image != null){
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A little bit ox explanation about this code for the benefit of the OP and others, would do this answer justice.